# Efficient way to count Columns

Tags: c#, count, text-files, multiple-columns

I need some efficient way to count columns in .txt file. My file format:

```
123.222  333.333  454.45  453.333
14.222  3.333  434.45  423.333
33.2  223.333  434.45  153.333
```

So I tried this one:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_path);
int ColumnsCount = Array.ConvertAll(sr.ReadLine().Split('  '), Double.Parse).Count();
```

First line is enough to get column count in this text format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are *almost* as fast as you can go. If you need the conversion, just do this:

```
int ColumnsCount = Array.ConvertAll(sr.ReadLine().Split(' '), Double.Parse).Length;
```

Using `Length` instead of `Count` saves you an enumeration of the collection. If you *don't* need to convert, just do:

```
sr.ReadLine().Split(' ').Length;
```

Otherwise, you still need to always do the read, and always `Split` the line. Since there is no way around that, its as fast as you can go.

Comment: Test this! It is not compilable. Change `'   '` (three blanks) to either `' '` (one blank) or `"   "` (three blanks).

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I just copied his code for that part. Good catch though, I've fixed it.

Comment: Actually its not three blanks its "tab separator" as long as i cant use it here i just use three blanks, anyway it's not the question point - three or four blanks or any other separator doesn't matters ...

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid `double.Parse`, since you are only interested in the column count and use `Split` with remove empty entries option. You can also use `File.ReadLine` and just read the first line like:

```
string firstLine = File.ReadLines("filePath").First();
int ColumnsCount = 0;
if (firstLine != null)
{
    ColumnsCount = firstLine.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
}
```

How much faster this would be, I am not sure, even if there is going to be a difference I believe it would be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick answer to this. No need to do the string split, simply treat the string as a character array, and count the spaces.  This also assumes that you cannot have a 0 column table.

```
var columnCount = 1;
foreach(var c in File.ReadLines("filePath").First() ?? String.Empty)
{
   if (c == ' ')
   {
      columnCount++;
   }
}

return columnCount;
```